# How to disable script errors in CHM. (Windows Help Format)

Tags: windows, html, chm

Recently [I requested for the Android Documentation in CHM format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854088/android-documentation-in-chm-format/8469098#8469098) on stackoverflow, the dude helped and did a conversion of the HTML data to a CHM format. However each page has some sort of script error, saying :

> An error has occurred on this page. Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?

It happens on the hundreds of pages in the CHM and I have to click NO, a couple of times, **how can I disable this**? I think it is somehow linked with Windows Internet Explorer.

Thanks.

Edit :

I found [this](http://www.technibble.com/how-to-stop-internet-explorer-script-error-messages/) but it doesn't work for CHMs. Help.

> How to stop the Internet explorer script error message from showing
>   up: You can tell your Internet Explorer to ignore these errors when
>   they occur and not show you an alert about them. Here is the
>   procedure: Open Internet Explorer In the top menu, Click on Tools and
>   then Internet Options Click on the Advanced Tab Find where it says
>   “Disable Script Debugging” and tick the box beside it Now, Find where
>   it says “Display a notification about every script error” and untick
>   the box beside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never Mind. I just downloaded this : http://www.extrachm.com/

It works without errors.

Comment: If this completely solved the problem, you should mark your own answer as accepted by clicking the checkbox.

Comment: This link is broken

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me ( I was getting 3 Internet Explorer Script Errors on each page of a compiled help .chm file, and I had to click "Yes" to continue running scripts.  This was painful - and I eventually found this question and answer )

Another answer said it didn't work, but it clearly worked for me - so it is worth posting as a potential answer for the reader in search of a solution

I'm running:

- hh.exe   version  5.2.3790.2453
- Microsoft Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3
- Internet Explorer 8   Version 8.0.6001.18702

So how to stop the Internet explorer script error message from showing
up?

You can tell your Internet Explorer to ignore these errors when
they occur and not show you an alert about them.

Here is the procedure:

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. In the top menu, Click on "Tools" and then "Internet Options"
3. Click on the "Advanced Tab"
4. Find where it says

   > Disable Script Debugging

   and tick the box beside it.
5. Now, find where it says

   > Display a notification about every script error

   and untick the box beside it.